# Convert String to datetime(timezone different) and save to database

Tags: java

I will receive datatime with

```
String format(eg: "2015-07-30-17.23.49.284526")
```

and save it to oracle database. But the value is based on other timezone. How should i convert it to database specific value and based on local timezone?

Comment: Separate it, then do what you want. After all, merge them.

Comment: What is the timezone of your string?

Comment: the string is generated by the server in Sweden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are using joda-time. if not. Suggest try to use it.

Check the code if it worked for you:

```
    public static Timestamp convertStringToTimestampWithTimeZone(String fromTimeZone, String toTimeZone, String input){
        String pattern = "yourdatetimeformat";
        DateTime dt  = DateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern)).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone
            .forID(fromTimeZone)).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(toTimeZone));
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(dt.getMillis());
        return ts;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the zoneid of the input string, current solution with `ZonedDateTime` java 8

Your input string in Sweden is UTC+1

```
try {
    ZoneId fromZoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC+1");
    String input = "2015-07-30-17.23.49.284526";                    
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS");
    LocalDateTime dateTimeWithoutZone = LocalDateTime.parse(input, pattern);
    ZonedDateTime fromZonedDateTime = dateTimeWithoutZone.atZone(fromZoneId);
    ZonedDateTime localZonedDateTime = fromZonedDateTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());                    
    System.out.println(localZonedDateTime.format(pattern));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I forget to mention that i'm working on java 7.